# Force layout node rotation

Tags: d3.js, rotation, force-layout

Ok, first - [look at this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/18na88m7/).
You should see shapes rotating back and forth like crazy.

This is what is going on:

```
force.on("tick", function(e) {
  vis.selectAll("path")
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"

              // this is the thing
              +"rotate(" + Math.random() * 50 + ")";
    });
});
```

On every tick I'm changing the `transform: rotate()` to `Math.random() * 50` in this case.

Now what I want is a smooth rotation. Not this jerky stuff.

See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/kor6ec2h/) to better understand what I mean. Imagine the height as the rotation. The gray box represents what I have now, the blue - what I want.

I tried applying `'transition: all 1s ease'` CSS to that element, but it just ignores it, I'm obviously doing it wrong.
So how do I make this infinite back and forth rotation smooth as if I was using CSS3 transitions?

Comment: You can apply a transition in D3: https://jsfiddle.net/18na88m7/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every tick you are randomly setting the rotation to something between 0 and 50 degrees of rotation. You need to maintain the current rotation, calculate an offset, and then set the rotation to the current + offset.

Here's an updated tick function:

```
force.on("tick", function(e) {
  vis.selectAll("path")
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        if(!d.rotate) { 
            d.rotate = Math.random() * 50;
        } else {
            d.rotate = d.rotate + 1;
        }
        return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"
              +"rotate(" + d.rotate + ")";
    });
});
```

Here's the updated working example: https://jsfiddle.net/1aLc7x4j/

Comment: Ok here's another [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kor6ec2h/) to illustrate what I have now (gray box), and what I want to achieve (blue box). Imagine that the height of the box is the rotation.
You made me realize that I can't accomplish this by setting a random rotation on each tick unless I use something like [Perlin noise](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-8lS7UCxUQRM/UGGq8keUy5I/AAAAAAAAAQ0/6QmeC_2zTpg/s1600/noise_vs_random.PNG) to generate the values.

Comment: I think we need to back up. What are you actually trying to accomplish here? What does rotation represent in your visualization? I suspect that the tick callback is the wrong place to manage rotation transitions in your case, but without understanding your end-goal, it's hard to say.